# Animation doesn't play in one state

Tags: unity, animation, animator

I have created an Animator and two sprite-based Animations. Both Animations preview correctly. In the Animator, I have created two states and two transitions between them based on a Boolean parameter. In the GameObject's script, the Boolean value is set based on distance to the player. When the player is far away Animation A plays and when the player is close Animation B plays.

However, while the transition from Animation A to B happens correctly when the player gets close, I only see the first frame of Animation B and it doesn't animate. If while in Play mode I preview Animation B (using the Animation window controls), it animates correctly.

Meanwhile, Animation A always plays correctly when it is supposed to.

What could cause this behavior? How can I get Animation B to play during runtime and not just when previewing? What's going on?

Edit:
Some screenshots. "Saw slow" is "Animation A" above, and "Saw fast" is "Animation B".

[image: Animator]
Animator

[image: Animator State - Slow]
Animator State - Slow

[image: Animator State - Fast]
Animator State - Fast

[image: Transition: slow to fast]
Transition: slow to fast

[image: Transition: fast to slow]
Transition: fast to slow

[image: Animation - Slow]
Animation - Slow

[image: Animation - Fast]
Animation - Fast

The code is very simple:

```
bool trigger = playerDistanceSqr < (activeDistance * activeDistance);
animator.SetBool("IsFast", trigger);
```

Comment: This is definitely the type of thing you should include pictures of - it's very hard for us to visualise what your code and graphs look like with just words.

Comment: Is there any difference at all in how you've configured the parameters for these two states or transitions? Can you show us?

Comment: Are both animations configured to loop?

Comment: Aha! That's what I overlooked. The "Fast" animation did not have "Loop Time" checked.